# Add space to stargazer descriptive table

Tags: r, stargazer

[image]

I have this table when I run this code in R. However the numbers are so close to each other, I was wondering if there is any way I could make the space gap bigger between them?

Code:
Data %>% stargazer (type="html",title = " Summary statistics of the samples", align = TRUE,
out="Variables Descriptive.html")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way through the `stargazer` function, but I found a workaround. I've included two ways to do this because I don't know if you're using this in RMD or using the file "Variables Descriptive.html". If you're using the HTML file in RMD (outside of R code), follow the instructions for modifying the HTML file.

### Option 1: Using R Markdown

Add the following before you get to the chunk that executes this table—not in a code chunk.

```
<style>
.myTable > table {
  width: 75%;
}
</style>
```

Add the following immediately before the code chunk that executes the table add the following—not in a code chunk.

```
<div class="myTable">
```

Add the following immediately after the code chunk that executes the table—not in a code chunk.

```
</div>
```

It will look something like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "2/24/2022"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(stargazer)
```


<style>
.myTable > table {
  width: 75%;
}
</style>

<div class="myTable">

```{r cars, results="asis"}

stargazer(attitude, type = "html", align = T, header = F,
          title = " Summary statistics of the samples", 
          out = "var.html")
```

<div>
````

After you see the output, you can adjust the width accordingly. Depending on the screen size, the width will change. However, this also ensures that the spacing is evenly dispersed.

[image]

[image]

### Option 2: Using the HTML file

You could use any text editor to open the file. I used the source pane of RStudio by going to the *File* tab, left-clicking on the name of the .HTML file, and selecting *Open in Editor*.

[image]

You will see the HTML code in your source pane now. The first tag is the *table* tag; that's what we're going to change.

Currently it states:

```
<table style="text-align:center">
```

You are going to add the inline CSS here. Add a semi-colon to the end of the inline styles in the code. In this example, I added a semi-colon after `center`. Then add `width: 75%;`. Make sure that you've not erased the closing parentheses or closing tag `">`.

Save the file. You can select *Preview* from the menu bar within the *Source* pane with this HTML code or you can go back to the *File* pane and *View in Browser* to see the changes. Just like before, the size of the viewing screen will change the size of the table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, i used the second option and it worked great!